# Is it possible to have a C++ function or macro that writes the code of another function to file as a string?

Tags: c++, function, macros

Is it possible to have a function write the contents (i.e. the actual code) of another function to a file? For instance say we have a function that adds two numbers:

```
int add(int a, int b){
    return a + b;
}
```

would it be possible to have another function or macro that would write this function as a string to a file?

```
void functionThatWritesAddToAFile(std::string fname){
    
}
```

The reason I want this is to autogenerate my documentation examples. I want to be able to write code examples (preferably as googletests, but as simple functions is also fine) and run them, then have the code examples be saved into a file at a known location which would be read automatically by my documentation (using `sphinx`s `.. literalinclude:: fname` directive). This way, when code changes, the examples automatically get updated.

Comment: No, that would not be possible. If you want to document your source code, you need a tool that can read and parse source code. A random C program is not such tool.

Comment: Everything is possible in C++. You just have to write the code to do it. But for the described purpose, the correct approach is to use a documentation tool. There are already many, freely available, source code documentation tools that exist and can be used, and unless your specific program is so specialized that none of them produce satisfactory results, then simply using them will be the easiest solution. Have you tried to use one of these tools, like doxygen, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have much recent experience with C++ but I think it's possible to at least read the contents of a text file and copy it over to another? Obviously you can't have the code you'd like to copy running at the same time but if you need just to copy the contents and save it to a different location that's possible. The function could maybe look like:

1. open file
2. read contents
3. store contents as string
4. create new file at location
5. write contents in new file
6. close file

...something like this?
Python uses `open()`,`read()`,`write()` functions/methods and I'd imagine C++ has something similar

Comment: Indeed! A separate program that does it would be much easier. This is a much simpler solution. Thanks for the input.